# Как передать cookie (сессию) на поддомен WordPress (не мультисайт)

Tags: wordpress, cookie, сессия

есть домен с WordPress на борту.
Нужно было решение для вывода страницы на поддомен, при этом, что бы сама страница была на основном домене. Нашел решение с помощью плагина: [Page As Subdomain Lite](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/page-as-subdomain-lite/) в cPanel создал поддомен указав ему в качестве папки путь к основному домену (вместо предложенного поддомена). Все работает, хорошо, CORS Policy не беспокоит, SSL так же. Но вот как синхронизировать авторизацию, корзину WooCommerce и остальное с основным доменом? При попытке авторизации просто перебрасывает на основной домен.
Пробовал прописывать общие куки (из древнего мануала по мультисайту) таким образом:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.my-domain.com'); //Перед именем домена обязательно ставьте точку! Это указание на область применения cookie
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');

// изменяем имена куки
$publick_hash = md5('https://my-domain.com');
define('USER_COOKIE', 'wordpressuser_' . $publick_hash);
define('PASS_COOKIE', 'wordpresspass_' . $publick_hash);
define('AUTH_COOKIE', 'wordpress_' . $publick_hash);
define('SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE', 'wordpress_sec_' . $publick_hash);
define('LOGGED_IN_COOKIE', 'wordpress_logged_in_' . $publick_hash);
define('TEST_COOKIE', 'wordpress_test_cookie_' . $publick_hash);
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/' ); //Если не прописывать эту директиву, то пользователь не сможет зайти в админку
define('PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH', '/' ); //Аналогично, но для плагинов
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

Но это результата не дало, есть ли у кого ни будь какие идеи по этому поводу?

Comment: Никак. Авторизация в WP построена так, что в хеш пишется домен. Используйте мультисайт.

Comment: И да, WooCommerce не будет работать на мультисайт. Нужно сильно платное расширение.